# ClickjackingPreventionFilter in jsp: @WebFilter vs CustomFilter

Tags: java

So in jsp i'm trying to prevent Clickjacking,

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", initParams = @WebInitParam(name="mode", value="SAMEORIGIN"))
public class ClickjackingPreventionFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        res.addHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SMAEORIGIN" );
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Ppl suggested to use custom filter instead of WebFilter.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

I'm trying to understand the difference.

To my little understanding, WebFilter is a standard filter, i just need to pass parameters.
Vs custom filter is a "custom" filter as its name says.

Any comments on which way i should go ? Thx !

Comment: Does you project use Spring or standard JEE?

Comment: @stdunbar We use spring, java 8